# How can I reset an adf page without hardcoding it explicitly?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a form with few input boxes,Select boxes etc.

How can I reset the control values to null/empty without writing the code. I mean is there any property which automatically resets the page or controls?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
       <af:commandLink text="commandLink with resetActionListener"
                            id="cl1" immediate="true" actionListener="#{demoInput.reset}">
         <af:resetActionListener/>
       </af:commandButton>
```

More info [here](http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_resetActionListener.html).

Comment: That example is from the documentation in the link. You don't always need to implement that action listener. I implemented that action listener in one case where I had autoSubmit="true" on a select box. In this case when the select was changed the new value was already submitted, so I had to manually keep track of that change and reset it to the initial value in the action listener.